# Parts of PHP code display on page?

Tags: php, html, apache

Parts of my PHP code are displaying on the page!  I have read several other questions asking the same thing but none of their answers or suggestions work for me.  I have also run my code through a syntax checker to see if there is anything wrong with it. Here is my code:

```
<?php  

function serverChecker( $ip, $port )  {
    error_reporting (0); 
    $up = fsockopen( $ip, $port, $errno, $errstr, 30 );   
    if( $up ) {
    echo '<span class="serveronline">Online</span>';   
        }; 
    else { 
    echo '<span class="serveroffline">Offline</span>';  
        };

};

?>
```

And then farther down the page:

```
<h4>Webserver</h4> - <?php serverChecker( "mywebserver.com", 80); ?>
```

I am rather unexperienced at PHP so my code may not be the greatest.

Thanks, 
**edit:** Ok so to answer some of your questions: 
- 1. My problem is part of my php code IS showing on the page (the code itself) and my code does not work now because it does this.
- 2. My question is how can I change it so that it works.

**edit 2:**  I have put my code in a [gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8a4f3fc208ca4d92a9c2).  The function begins on line 36 and it is called on line 216.  Also here is a screenshot of what is wrong with how the page displays:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Qpiq.jpg

(it is a screenshot of only the top left part of the page)

**edit 3:** For now I will find some other code because I need to get this done.  But I would still like to figure out how to fix it.

Comment: May I see the full code please?

Comment: Which part is displaying?

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: you dont have to put semi colon after curly braces in your if else statement

Comment: Maybe he is trying to say aren't displaying on the page!

Comment: Is it *parts* or *all* of your PHP code? If it looks the same in "view source" as it does in your .php file, then it sounds like Apache is not configured to execute PHP scripts.

Comment: see this `fsockopen( $ip, $port, $errno, $errstr, 30 );` so where is $errno and $errstr?

Comment: As I said in the question, I am not very good at PHP so I got the base of my code from http://forums.winamp.com/showthread.php?t=166910 Should I remove those?  They were there in the original code so I left them.

Comment: Also you need properly setted PHP handler. Seems PHP code is not interpreted. You can see all code in HTML source of the page.

Comment: @DrixsonOseña I removed the $errno and $errorstr variables in my code and I got a blank page.  I ran my .php file through the command `php -l` and I got `PHP Fatal error:  Only variables can be passed by reference in index.php on line 40`

Answer (score -2):

I agree with  Drixson Oseña,

Have you tried removing the unnecessary semi colons after your function and if statements? Like below.

```
<?php  

function serverChecker( $ip, $port )  {
    error_reporting (0); 
    $up = fsockopen( $ip, $port, $errno, $errstr, 30 );   
    if( $up ) {
    echo '<span class="serveronline">Online</span>';   
        }
    else { 
    echo '<span class="serveroffline">Offline</span>';  
        }

}

?>
```

Comment: Yes. That's how it was before and I thought that maybe that was the problem: not having semicolons in the right places. That didn't seem to affect anything and the problem persisted.

Comment: @JesseWallace restart the web-server and all caching services like memcache, opcache etc.

Comment: I tried that and nothing different happened @Deaddooshka